# Setting up development environment for OpenBTS

Tags: linux, gsm, usrp

I want to make some little changes in OpenBTS code and use it. Currently I am following this process

1. Make some changes in code. ( Can't do testing of these changes at runtime)
2. Build the packages
3. Install the packages
4. Setup or Run OpenBTS
5. Test the behavior of OpenBTS to see that those changes are reflected or not.
6. If not working, goto step 1

This a quite hectic process, is there any smarter way to do it. Like OpenBTS is directly run from code, rather than packages installed on Ubuntu. If I make change in code, and they are directly reflected in my setup. How i can setup this dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit late, I have just started to work on this my self. I don't bother installing the packages each time. My cycle is more like this:

1. Build the packages
2. Setup/run the database scripts (init the databases)
3. Install the packages that I don't need to re-build
4. Run each package manually (from the open BTS folders), e.g. run ../Transceiver, ../sipauthserver, ../OpenBTS, ../OpenBTSCLI ...etc...

Then when I want to make a code change - I do:

1. Stop everything
2. Code change
3. Re-build (e.g. just openBTS)
4. Re-run everything as before.

I also scripted the startup / stop sequences to make this faster (open/run each app in new terminals)